# Bash : command line with optional arguments

Tags: bash, quoting, arguments

I'm running this kind of code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -u
exclude1='--exclude=/path/*'
exclude2='--exclude=/path with spaces/*'
exclude3=''        # any 'exclude' can be empty
tar -czf backup.tgz "$exclude1" "$exclude2" "$exclude3" 2>&1 | grep -i 'my_reg_exp' > error.log
RESULT=("${PIPESTATUS[@]}")
... etc ...
```

When I run this code, I get this error:

```
tar: : Cannot stat: No such file or directory
```

This is because "$exclude3" is translated as an empty argument. Exactly as if I did this:

```
tar -czf backup.tgz "$exclude1" "$exclude2" ''
```

One way to avoid this error is to remove the double quotes around $excludeX. But this is a problem if $excludeX contains any space or other strange characters.

Another way would be to use `eval` but because I need to keep the double quotes, I don't see how to suppress the quotes AND the empty arguments when needed.

The only solution I found is to construct the command-line with string concatenation:

```
CMD='tar -czf backup.tgz'
if [[ -n "$exclude1" ]]; then CMD+=" \"$exclude1\" "; fi
if [[ -n "$exclude2" ]]; then CMD+=" \"$exclude2\" "; fi
if [[ -n "$exclude3" ]]; then CMD+=" \"$exclude3\" "; fi
eval $CMD 2>&1 | grep -i 'my_reg_exp' > error.log
RESULT=("${PIPESTATUS[@]}")
... etc ...
```

Anyone have a smarter idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
tar -czf backup.tgz "$exclude1" "$exclude2" ${exclude3+"$exclude3"} 2>&1
```

`${exclude3+"$exclude3"}` expands to nothing, if `$exclude3` is unset, and to `"$exclude3"`, if it is set.

(and similarly for the other variables that are potentially unset.)

Note that there is a difference between an unset variable and a variable that is set to the empty string, so you should use

```
unset exclude3
```

instead of

```
exclude3=''
```

Comment: Nice trick, but if $exclude3 is unset then Bash will issue an error because 'set -u' is used as a safety measure.

Comment: It works as long as you only _test_ whether the variable is set or not. Testing doesn't count as _trying to perform parameter expansion on the variable_.

Comment: By the way, there is a related construction that treats unset and empty variables in the same way, namely `${exclude3:+"$exclude3"}` (note the colon).

Answer (score 7):

Since you're working in bash, use an [array](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays).

```
excludes=()
excludes+=('--exclude=/path/*')
…
tar -czf backup.tgz "${excludes[@]}"
```

If you have an optional entry in some variable, add it in a conditional.

```
if [[ -n $exclude_or_empty ]]; then excludes+=("$exclude_or_empty"); fi
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in bash on Ubuntu, but I have no clue, whether it's POSIX compliant/compatible:

```
tar -czf backup.tgz \
$(if "$exclude1" != ""); then echo "$exclude1"; fi
$(if "$exclude2" != ""); then echo "$exclude3"; fi
$(if "$exclude3" != ""); then echo "$exclude3"; fi
```